# pypy how to find the file about implement list type

Tags: python, list, cpython, pypy

how to find python list implement on pypy
i want read the source code
bui i didn't find it
any one could give a help
thanks

Comment: Where have you looked? And why is this tagged [cpython]?

Answer (score 4):

Did you look around their [dev guide](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/coding-guide.html)? It gives good idea of how [source code](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy) is laid out.

From the docs:

> The Standard Object Space (pypy/objspace/std/) is the direct equivalent of CPython’s object library (the “Objects/” subdirectory in the distribution). It is an implementation of the common Python types in a lower-level language.

And browsing through the code gives [listobject.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/5e2a8b1e5782/pypy/objspace/std/listobject.py) and [listtype.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/5e2a8b1e5782/pypy/objspace/std/listtype.py), that will be relevant to you.